# My mouse always interprets a left-click as a middle click. How can I restore normal behavior?

Tags: mouse

My High Sierra Mac is interpreting any left mouse click as a middle click. So that means it won't switch context to a desired window with a left click, and all web links open in a background tab, as if I were holding the Cmd key when clicking (which I'm not). Here's what I've tried:

- Using a different mouse. My normal is the magic mouse, also tried an M720 Logitech over bluetooth. Both have the same issue.
- Turning off my bluetooth keyboard. I thought maybe it was messed up, and telling the Mac that the Cmd was being held down. Turning it off had no effect.
- Restarting the Mac. This didn't help.
- Reviewing mouse settings. Nothing I changed seemed to help. Even tried reversing the left/right button functionality, but not difference.

I'm out of ideas here. What can I try to resolve it?

Comment: Could you try in safe mode and see if it still happens?

Comment: Ok, I feel dumb now. I went to start in safe mode, and remembered that I also had a wired keyboard plugged in, and thought "I should use that for the shift key on restart." I then saw it had my headphones resting on the Cmd key.... Needless to say, taking the headphones off fixed the problem. Dopey mistake but @SkeletonBow comments helped me find it.

Comment: Haha, I didn't do much but glad you got it sorted!